# Lazy evaluation of supplied arguments

Tags: r, lazy-evaluation

Say I have the following function:

```
foo <- function(x, y = min(m)) {
    m <- 1:10
    x + y
}
```

When I run `foo(1)`, the returned value is `2`, as expected. However, I cannot run `foo(1, y = max(m))` and receive `11`, since lazy evaluation only works for default arguments. How can I supply an argument but have it evaluate lazily?

Comment: "lazy evaluation only works for default arguments", are you sure about that? IIUC lazy evaluation happens with all function arguments. The reason your example doesn't work is because m is not in the caller's scope.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simple answer is that you can't and shouldn't try to.  That breaks scope and could wreak havoc if it were allowed.  There are a few options that you can think about the problem differently.

first pass y as a function

```
foo<-function(x,y=min){
m<-1:10
x+y(m)
}
```

if a simple function does not work you can move m to an argument with a default.

```
foo<-function(x,y=min(m),m=1:10){
x+y(m)
}
```

Since this is a toy example I would assume that this would be too trivial. If you insist on breaking scope then you can pass it as an expression that is evaluated explicitly.

```
foo<-function(x,y=expression(min(m))){
m<-1:10
x+eval(y)
}
```

Then there is the option of returning a function from another function.  And that might work for you as well, depending on your purpose.

```
bar<-function(f)function(x,y=f(m)){
m<-1:10
x+y
}
foo.min<-bar(min)
foo.min(1)  #2
foo.max<-bar(max)
foo.max(1)  #10
```

But now we are starting to get into the ridiculous.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to just change the default argument:

```
R> formals(foo)$y <- call("max", as.name("m"))
R> foo(1)
[1] 11
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `substitute`, `eval` combintation.

```
foo <- function(x, y = min(m)) {
  y <- substitute(y)
  m <- 1:10
  x + eval(y)
}

foo(1)
## [1] 2
foo(1, y = max(m))
## [1] 11
```